# How can I extract json data from snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm working with Snowflake, and have a batch of JSON data in a variant datatype.  I'm going to paste just the first entry (I hope) out of megabytes of data.

I need to figure out the SQL to extract the data elements from it.

This query:

```
SELECT 
    src:value::string AS valuest,
    src:value:evaluation_forms as evaluation_forms,
    src:value:evaluation_forms:evaluations as evaluations,
    src:value:evaluation_forms:evaluations:channel_meta as channel_meta,
    src:value:evaluations:channel_meta:agent_first_name as agent_first_name
FROM stage.intuit_quality_raw_table
```

retrieves JSON data in valuest, JSON data in evaluation_forms, and nulls in evaluations, channel_meta, and agent_first_name.

I suspect that that is because of the '[' characters that occur in from of the evaluations and channel_meta entries, but I just don't know how to deal with that sort of data.

I aplogize the being so long.  The first entry is something over 300 lines long, and I'm afraid to try to shorten it because I fear that I will delete something important.  I've already added the ending batch of stuff, which I'm also afraid that I might have messed up.

Anyway, here it is:

```
{"value": 
 {"evaluation_forms": 
  [ {"evaluations": 
   [ {"channel_meta": 
      {"after_call_work_time": [], 
       "agent_first_name": ["KATRINA"],
       "agent_hung_up": [],
       "agent_last_name": ["COX"],
       "agent_unique_id": ["LO_00130604"], 
       "agent_username": [], 
       "alternate_call_id": [], 
       "audio_file_name": ["b161aa50-cda9-42e2-ad16-117a9cf08b92.wav"],
       "call_direction": ["INBOUND"], 
       "call_id": ["b161aa50-cda9-42e2-ad16-117a9cf08b92"], 
       "channel_type": "Call",               
       "customer_id": [],               
       "customer_segment": [],               
       "disposition": [],
       "disposition_time": [], 
       "end_at": ["2023-01-24 12:00:00"],
       "file_location": ["blank"], 
       "handle_time": ["1824"],
       "hold_time": [],               
       "how_call_ended": ["Transferred"],
       "how_call_originated": [],               
       "id": "3cb5a3e5-0ab8-4a38-9f6b-4ab3b2e24351",
       "ivr_options": [],               
       "line": ["Intuit"],
       "notes": [],               
       "queue": ["Product Support"],
       "queue_time": [],               
       "start_at": ["2023-01-24 12:00:00"]       
       "subqueue": [ "Product Support - Desktop"   ],
       "supplemental_field_1": ["Expert Service Score: 3"],
       "supplemental_field_10": [],               
       "supplemental_field_2": ["Derived TNPS Score: 0"],    
       "supplemental_field_3": [],   
       "supplemental_field_4": [], 
       "supplemental_field_5": [],
       "supplemental_field_6": [],
       "supplemental_field_7": [],
       "supplemental_field_8": [],
       "supplemental_field_9": [],
       "talk_time": ["78"],
       "team_id": [],               
       "times_held": ["2"],
       "total_time": []             
      },             
      "evaluation_list": [               
      {"evaluation_meta": 
       {"ack_info": 
        {"ack_init_time":
         null,
         "ack_status": "NOT_INITIATED",
         "ack_time": null,
         "dispute_raised_at": null,
         "dispute_raised_by_email": null,
         "dispute_resolved_at": null,
         "dispute_resolved_by_email": null
         },
         "agent_email": "lo_00130604@liveopsnation.com",
         "agent_id": "63d77af042a6982e25008bf3",
         "agent_name": "KATRINA COX",
         "agent_status": "ACTIVE",
         "created_at": "2023-02-06T02:16:53.637Z",
         "evaluation_purpose": null,
         "evaluation_type": "Manual",
         "evaluator_email": "info@ara-gs.com",
         "evaluator_id":"63cb37e42db1035ae08285d1",
         "evaluator_name": "RAMON CARPIO JR�",
         "evaluator_status": "ACTIVE",
         "id": "63e06221ea5e4c7202572252",
         "modified_at": "2023-02-06T02:17:35.229Z",
         "status": "EDITED"                 
        },                 
        "response": {                   
        "comment": "",                   
        "sections": [
        {                       
         "id": "3fe2faeb-e8bc-4a16-9fd1-49166a3eed4d",
         "questions": [
           {
             "comment": "",
             "fail": false,                           
             "id": "4c057d99-aae7-4432-8634-6c41e4cde734",
             "score_obtained": 1,                           
             "value": "Yes" 
            },                         
            {"comment": "",                           
             "fail": false,                           
             "id": "f23b5e63-b24c-49f7-aa46-eb7499cdf89d",
             "score_obtained": 1,                           
             "value": "Yes"                         
        },                         
        {"comment": "",  
        "fail": false,                           
        "id": "4798443d-eaf3-46e7-bc9f-1f03ccee871a",
        "score_obtained": 1,                           
        "value": "Yes"                         
        }],                       
        "score_obtained": 3                     
        },                     
        {"id": "f5a83974-3be3-4f69-a9de-49866213b383",
        "questions": [                         {
        "comment": "",                           
        "fail": false,                           
        "id": "52ec152b-fce8-464d-a8cf-b4ae82bfb5d9",
        "score_obtained": 0,                           
        "value": "N/A"                         
        },                         
        {"comment": "",
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "627ce8fd-2d29-44d9-8c3d-49dfdab9f7b2",
         "score_obtained": 0,                           
         "value": "N/A"
         },                         
         { "comment": "",                           
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "a6efd5fe-42e1-4411-b197-ee715b579281",   
         "score_obtained": 0,                           
         "value": "N/A"                         
         },                         
         {"comment": "",                           
         "fail":false,                           
         "id": "aea7d958-c27e-44ab-a32f-c2388b8c6aab",
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "Yes"                         
         }, 
         {"comment": "",                           
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "860ac0b2-c325-443d-8f91-63879d09bac8",
         "score_obtained": 0,                           
         "value": "N/A"                         
         }                       ],                       
         "score_obtained": 1
         },                     
         {"id": "6a5fa573-8dc5-4dbb-b6cd-2e01445c3b4c",
         "questions": [                         
         {"comment": "",
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "22e2cc11-c886-4b56-8de6-e97b773de4d0",
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "Yes"
         },                         
         {"comment": "Agent transferred call incorrectly. Another agent advised her of it then call disconnected. ",                           
         "fail":true,                           
         "id": "39b2ab0d-7372-408e-b8e2-886be10239de",
         "score_obtained": 0,                           
         "value": "No"}
         ],                       
         "score_obtained": 1                     
         },                     
         {"id": "d1deed99-e8aa-49f1-8c32-079887fd6838",
         "questions": [
         {"comment": "",                           
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "b951c53c-52b9-4a08-b3c6-70298643db22", 
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "Yes"                         
         },                         
         {"comment": "",
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "2321f675-01f9-4975-b7e9-d57feb865d0e",
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "Yes"
         },                         
         {"comment": "",                           
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "6b0eb24c-f31c-41f0-85d3-56805d42284d",
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "Yes"                         
         },                         
         {"comment": "",                           
         "fail":false,                           
         "id": "7e5e7a2e-60c0-4416-814e-fe19c9ab2361",
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "Yes"                         
         },
         {                           
         "comment": "",                           
         "fail": false,                           
         "id": "19f6ec0a-4c4c-49b6-962e-d029a0326d27",
         "score_obtained": 1,                           
         "value": "No"                         
         }                       ],                       
         "score_obtained": 5                     
         },                     
         {"id": "6c41a906-3d69-469d-9391-c814a6124ec1",
          "questions": [                         
          {"comment": "",
          "fail": false,                           
          "id": "d72fca9d-323d-4238-980e-c0aec746e1fc",
          "score_obtained": 1,                           
          "value": "Yes"},                         
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "d1af8d8e-6a97-4111-bad7-a64695f2c3f7",
          "score_obtained": 1,
          "value": "Yes"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail":true,
          "id": "c1251cb6-c3fe-4f69-bbe5-9510f150d18a",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          }],
          "score_obtained": 2
          },
          {
          "id": "ca1c275b-1cd0-49c9-a4d7-9fd0544b4bbf",
          "questions": [
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": true,
          "id": "4f3268ba-4e8d-46b8-a50a-69ea9de88a6a",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": true,
          "id": "cb82d886-8e2c-4d4c-a8f8-b5c769bf289a",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": true,
          "id": "ea9aa819-6905-4f15-a702-3713bbb033a9",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          } 
          ],
          "score_obtained": 0
          },
          {
          "id": "5743b6e8-ac6f-4d34-8561-f7e5191d5f37",
          "questions": [
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "af04685e-5c73-47be-8282-493960cce3e0",
          "score_obtained": 1,
          "value": "Yes"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "67b8ea9f-d481-42c2-9343-e586875e0929",
          "score_obtained": 1,
          "value": "Yes"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail":false,
          "id": "9fc25686-a63c-4db4-b2aa-dcf8666d2147",
          "score_obtained": 1,
          "value": "Yes"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "410616c0-0d41-4322-b6a3-df11c3c28963",
          "score_obtained": 1,
          "value": "Yes"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "575c978e-365d-4b83-842e-acfe41de09ae",
          "score_obtained": 1,
          "value": "Yes"
          } ],
          "score_obtained": 5
          },
          "id": "bced1392-24b2-404f-91be-9df6d68e0c8d",
          "questions": [
          { 
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "e2250777-8bba-4fee-b9b4-1535b42be14c",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "533281a0-63db-4af6-b41e-7b967a456332",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "c9cf8f64-427b-4927-8ffb-02454e6daa43",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          {
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "7c4df8ba-0d89-4703-b4fe-3e6f88c3fa76",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          "comment": "",
          "fail": false,
          "id": "0bf1e679-a300-475e-9fb8-613317d42570",
          "score_obtained": 0,
          "value": "No"
          },
          {
          "comment": "Advise agent get the link with forms update
dates to provide clients. No transfer needed to be completed. ",
        "   fail": false,
            "id": "52ba5be6-7def-469a-a31f-7c74c86730ac",
            "score_obtained": 0,
            "value": ""
            }
            ],
            "score_obtained": 0
            }
        ]},
        "scores_obtained": {
        "auto_fail": false,
        "final_score": 17,
        "grade_assigned": "Pass",
        "percent_score": 77.27,
        "total_bonus": 0,
        "total_penalties": 0,
        "total_points": 22
        }
    }
]
}

]}]}}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi - that’s not a valid JSON string (put it through one on the many online JSON validators and you’ll see all the issues). So I’d start by fixing those issues and once you have a valid JSON string see if your SQL works

Comment: Do you want me to post the entire 79000 line entry?  Can you just tell me how to deal with the ['s?

Comment: How do you know it is the [ causing the issue when there appear to be all sorts of other issues with your JSON? When I put your JSON through a validator it didn’t mention any issues with the [ - though I only looked at the first few errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use FLATTEN function to parse nested arrays in JSON.

refer to
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-semistructured#using-the-flatten-function-to-parse-nested-arrays

Comment: I've been working with flatten.  It's not working.  Here is my code.  I'm sure I doing something wrong.

SELECT 
    src:value::string AS valuest,
    src:value:evaluation_forms as evaluation_forms,
    src:value:evaluation_forms:evaluations as evaluations,
    src:value:evaluation_forms:evaluations:channel_meta as channel_meta,
    src:value:evaluations:channel_meta:agent_first_name as agent_first_name,
    *
  FROM stage.intuit_quality_raw_table iqr,
  LATERAL FLATTEN( INPUT => iqr.src, path=>'value' ) v,
  LATERAL FLATTEN( INPUT => v.value:evaluation_forms ) ef;

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, I have taken a small part of your JSON data and tested it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE xyz
( 
 src variant
 )
AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON(column1) AS src
FROM VALUES
('{"value": 
    {"evaluation_forms": 
        [ {"evaluations": 
            [ {"channel_meta": 
               {"after_call_work_time": [], 
                "agent_first_name": ["KATRINA"],
                "agent_hung_up": [],
               "agent_last_name": ["COX"]
              }
          } ]
     } ] 
   }
 } '
 ) v;


SELECT
  src:value AS valuest,
  src:value:evaluation_forms as evaluation_forms,
  v.value:evaluations as evaluations,
  ve.value:channel_meta as channel_meta,
  Fn.value as agent_first_name
  FROM
     xyz
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => SRC:value:evaluation_forms) v
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => v.value:evaluations) ve
    , LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => ve.value:channel_meta:agent_first_name) fn
    ;
```